# Difference between "almost surely finitely often" and "almost surely infinitely often"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is my understanding that in probability, and especially as a consequence from the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, "almost surely infinitely often" corresponds to some event $A_n$ whereby:

$$
P(\limsup A_n) =1
$$

However, I am not sure what "almost surely finitely often" means. Does this mean that:

$$
P(\limsup A_n) =0
$$
? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $\limsup A_n$ means
$$ \bigcap_{m\le 1} \bigcup_{n\le m} A_n $$
that is, the event that infinitely many of the $A_i$ events happen.

The complement of this is of course that only finitely of them happen, so indeed
$$ P(\limsup A_n)=0 $$
means that infinitely many of the $A_n$ happens *almost never*, which is the same as *only finitely many* $A_n$s happen *almost surely*.

---

(For comparison $\liminf A_n$ would be the event that *all of the $A_n$s happen together, with at most finitely many exceptions*).